# Creating a pressure sensitive pencil style in Gimp

Tags: gimp, sketching

I am new to GIMP and illustration in general but am trying to draw my own map and am following [this](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/2015/02/how-to-draw-a-map/) guide.

The first part of the guide is to sketch out the layout of the plan on the map and the author gives advice on how to setup the pencil. The results they achieve look like this:

[[image: Author Example Image]

I am using GIMP 2.8.14 and the best I can achieve, using the Pencil Generic Dynamics is:

[image: my attempt]

I wrote this using different pressures on my Wacom Bamboo and as you can see I am missing any sort of shading/transparancy from pressure.

My question is: WHat settings do I need to use, and how do I set them up, to copy the above pencil style in GIMP?

Comment: Pretty sure this is actually a driver issue for my older MTE-450 bamboo tablet. I will try and get the drivers working before closing the issue incase it is something else

Comment: Driver now correct and is still an issue in Gimp. Windows Sketchpad picks up the pressure input as varying

Comment: Did you make sure that the tablet is activated in GIMP's preferences?

Comment: Go to `Windows>Dockable dialogs>Device status`. If there is only one device, the tablet isn't seen as a tablet and is lumped with other pointers (mouse, trackpad...). If the stylus is dual-ended, you'll have three devices (one for each end of the stylus).

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher & xenoid. I certainly did check this before the driver issue. Once the driver was found I checked the input devices section and it doesn't show up in GIMP at all. I will try the device status suggestion tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is found by future Wacom users, this was definitly a driver issue. Once i found Windows 10 drivers, got them installed and restarted the PC it now shows up in gimp.
[image]

Comment: The main clue is that the tablet setup is OK is in the Device Status dialog (`Windows>Dockable dialog>Device status`). As long as your tablet isn't seen as pressure-sensitive, it is lumped with the other pressureless pointing devices into the "Core Pointer". When it is usable with pressure If it OK, it shows as additions device(s) (two devices for the tablets where the stylus has two active ends).

Comment: This is correct, although at one point it was working with other pieces of software and just not GIMP. I think that was before i did a full restart